# Passing image URL as a prop in Vue not working

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, vuejs2

I am new to Django Rest Framework and am trying to learn how to create a Full-Stack application with Django Rest Framework and VueJS.

I am using Django Rest Framework to deliver image URLs from the Django server to my Vue application. When I pass the imageURL as a prop, and bind the src attribute, the image is not displayed. When I go directly to the imageURL (in this example 127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/meal_1.jpg), it is the correct URL and the image displays correctly. If I manually set the src attribute, it displays correctly.

```
<img :src="imageURL" alt="Product Image"/>
{{ imageURL }}
```

[image: Binding the src attribute]

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/meal_1.jpg" alt="Product Image" />
{{ imageURL }}
```

[image: Manually setting the src attribute]

I have researched similar problems and they all mention using require(), but this image is not located in the Vue application's assets folder, is is getting served from the Django application. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try add`http://`?

Comment: That worked. Thanks Jay